# Error running Live Unit Testing: Project files not found after adding projects to solution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022, xunit, live-unit-tests

I created a solution for easy development and template creation. I have a project called InfoinaDDD, which consists of 2 parts, one part is the source code and the other part is its tests. And I have another project called myTemplate, which is the way to use the InfoinaDDD project, and I want to create a personal template for visual studio after the full development. The InfoinaDDD project itself is created from different layers, each of which is a class library, and a corresponding unit test project is created for each of them. I added all these projects in a solution called InfoinaFramework (Add -> Existing project) and added all the required references, the project is uploaded correctly and even the manual test is executed correctly.

But my problem is with Live Unit Testing.When I run live unit testing it gives me an error:

> [12:54:05 ب.ظ Info] Building 7 test projects.
> [12:54:05 ب.ظ Info] Loading projects.
> [12:54:05 ب.ظ Info] Building project 'InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources'.
> [12:54:05 ب.ظ Info] Build failed for project 'InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources'.
> [12:54:05 ب.ظ Error] Build completed with failures. Errors were logged under file:///C:/Users/Sibetalaee/source/lut/InfoinaFramework/v2/0/diag/build.minimal.log
> [12:56:11 ب.ظ Info] Live Unit Testing stopped.
> [12:56:14 ب.ظ Info] Live Unit Testing started.
> [12:56:14 ب.ظ Info] Building solution.
> [12:56:14 ب.ظ Info] Loading projects.
> [12:56:15 ب.ظ Info] Triggering NuGet package restore.
> [12:56:15 ب.ظ Info] Building project 'InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources'.
> [12:56:15 ب.ظ Info] Build failed for project 'InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources'.
> [12:56:15 ب.ظ Error] Build completed with failures. Errors were logged under file:///C:/Users/Sibetalaee/source/lut/InfoinaFramework/v2/0/diag/build.minimal.log

and wrote the following errors in the log file:
For the first test run:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\binaDDD\src\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\binaDDD\src\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
> 0 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.54

And for next time:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\3.Endpoints\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\3.Endpoints\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\Infoina.DDD.Framework.InfrastructureResource.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\0.Framework\InfoinaFramework\InfoinaDDD.Framework.InfoinaFramework.Utilities\Infoina.DDD.Framework.InfoinaFramework.Utilities.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain\Infoina.DDD.Core.Domain.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts\Infoina.DDD.Core.Contracts.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands\Infoina.DDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries\Infoina.DDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\3.Endpoints\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api\Infoina.DDD.Endpoints.Api.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\binaDDD\src\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\3.Endpoints\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\3.Endpoints\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\Infoina.DDD.Framework.InfrastructureResource.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\0.Framework\InfoinaFramework\InfoinaDDD.Framework.InfoinaFramework.Utilities\Infoina.DDD.Framework.InfoinaFramework.Utilities.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain\Infoina.DDD.Core.Domain.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts\Infoina.DDD.Core.Contracts.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands\Infoina.DDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries\Infoina.DDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\3.Endpoints\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api\Infoina.DDD.Endpoints.Api.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found.
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\binaDDD\src\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
> 0 Warning(s)
> 22 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.66

This error only happens for live unit testing and the tests are not executed, but the manual test works correctly. I restarted the live unit testing settings and received the same error. I ran the dotnet restore command at C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\binaDDD\src\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources and got the following error

> urces>dotnet restore
> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

I also ran the same command at this address where the sln file is, and I encountered the following errors:

> C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b>dotnet restore
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\Infoin
> aDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\Infoin
> aFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain.csproj" was no
> t found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts.csproj"
> was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService\InfoinaDDD.Core.Applicati
> onService.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\3.Endpoints\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api.cspro
> j" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources.Tests
> .Unit\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\Infoina
> Framework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain.Te
> sts.Unit.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contra
> cts.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.ApplicationService.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Co
> re.ApplicationService.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\Infoina
> Framework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\3.Endpoints\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Endpoin
> ts.Api.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\0.Framework\Resource\InfoinaDDD.Framework.Resource.Resources\Infoina.DDD.Frame
> work.InfrastructureResource.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFrame
> work.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\0.Framework\InfoinaFramework\InfoinaDDD.Framework.InfoinaFramework.Utilities\I
> nfoina.DDD.Framework.InfoinaFramework.Utilities.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework
> \v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Domain\Infoina.DDD.Core.Domain.csproj" was not found. [
> C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\1.Core\InfoinaDDD.Core.Contracts\Infoina.DDD.Core.Contracts.csproj" was not fo
> und. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Com
> mands\Infoina.DDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\Infoin
> aFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Que
> ries\Infoina.DDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaF
> ramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\LibrariesNugets\3.Endpoints\InfoinaDDD.Endpoints.Api\Infoina.DDD.Endpoints.Api.csproj" was not
> found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persiste
> nce.Sql.Commands\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source
> lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\src\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persiste
> nce.Sql.Queries\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\lu
> t\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persist
> ence.Sql.Queries.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Queries.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found. [C:\Use
> rs\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\NuGet.targets(398,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\l
> ut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\MyTemplates\InfoinaDDD\test\2.Infrastructure\Persistence\Sql\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persist
> ence.Sql.Commands.Tests.Unit\InfoinaDDD.Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql.Commands.Tests.Unit.csproj" was not found. [C:\U
> sers\Sibetalaee\source\lut\InfoinaFramework\v2\0\b\InfoinaFramework.sln]

Of course, I did the same thing through Visual Studio itself, and I didn't get an error:

> All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
> Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0388168
> Finished ==========

When I run the sln of the InfoinaDDD project and run live unit testing, it runs without any problem, but in the new sln I get the error as mentioned earlier. It should be noted that only the InfoinaDDD project has tests and the myTemplate project does not have any tests.

I have no idea how to solve the problem of live unit testing. Thanks in advance